# getInputStream throws Exception

Tags: android, inputstream, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to invoke a webservice and parse the returned XML, so my invoke URL is :

```
http://192.168.1.12/cr.ws/CarCategories.asmx/CarCategoryComparatorRQ?IdUser=1076&IdCurrency=1&IdLanguage=1&IdCarCategory=0&IdPickupRentCarAgencies=3&IdReturnRentCarAgencies=3&PickupDate=6/4/2011&ReturnDate=9/4/2011&Supplier=Prima%20Rent%20a%20Car&b=prima
```

in my browser I get the desired response :

```
<CarCategoryComparatorRS>
<CarCategory>
<IdCar>22</IdCar>
<IdCarCategory>22</IdCarCategory>
<Supplier>AvantGarde Rent a Car</Supplier>
<PickupRentCarAgencies>Tunis;  Aéroport de Tunis-Carthage</PickupRentCarAgencies>
<IdPickupRentCarAgencies>5</IdPickupRentCarAgencies>
<ReturnRentCarAgencies>Tunis;  Aéroport de Tunis-Carthage</ReturnRentCarAgencies>
<IdReturnRentCarAgencies>5</IdReturnRentCarAgencies>
<IdUser>705</IdUser>
<Title>Catégorie A [ex:Kia Rio;Renault Symbol]</Title>
<IdCurrency>1</IdCurrency>
<ImageUrl>Car-22-20090521-125545.jpg</ImageUrl>
<MemberReductionValue>0</MemberReductionValue>
<Rate>150</Rate>
<DelayRate>0</DelayRate>
<ReductionValue>135</ReductionValue>
<DayRate>45</DayRate>
<Reduction>10%</Reduction>
<AccompteValue>67.500</AccompteValue>
<Accompte>50</Accompte>
<TotalRate>0000135000</TotalRate>
</CarCategory>
</CarCategoryComparatorRS>
```

But this function trows java.io.FileNotFoundException

```
protected InputStream getInputStream() {
        try {
            return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Please help me, I wasted couple hours searching but nothing :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the spaces in this param :"Supplier=Prima Rent a Car", so i replaced this param by `UrlEncoder.encode("Supplier=Prima Rent a Car")` and it worked.

Comment: This method is deprecated. One should use URLEncoder.encode(String, String), where the second paramether is the encoding ("UTF-8" for an example)

Answer (score 0):

If you type that URL in your device's browser address bar do you get anything?

Comment: Yes i got the XML i mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to request an address on a local machine or LAN.  Are you requesting this on the android device? My guess is you need to run your server on the machine on a different interface or open up connections to the required port.

Comment: in fact the service runs on a real server, but for security reasons I changed the address by a local url.

Answer (score 0):

I think your url is being interpreted as a file url.

What about logging your url before you call `openConnection` as a sanity check:

```
Log.e("MyApp", feedUrl);
```

On second thought, could you post the logcat output? I'm skeptical as to how your code could ever throw a `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Finally I solved this, there's a param in that url which causes this error, so for this param i used UrlEncoder.encode(param) and it worked like a charm

Comment: Great. Might I ask which characters were causing the problem?

Comment: this param : "Supplier=Prima Rent a Car" the spaces between the words seem to be the cause